# How to display all posts with the same title in wordpress single.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an anime website in WordPress where I add episodes as posts.
I'm using a theme that i created by myself, what i want is to display the list of episodes of the anime that the user is watching by looping through the posts with the same title to display them all using PHP. I tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked.

In brief, I want to display posts with the same title to make a list of episodes

This is one of the solutions that i tried and didn't work.

```
<div class="episodes"> 
    <?php 
        $EpisodesList = new WP_Query('post_title='the_title()'');
        if ($EpisodesList->have_posts()) {
            while(have_posts()) {
                the_post();
                echo the_title( );
            } 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this via the post titles in the first place? WordPress has a taxonomy / category system - _and_ already provides "archive" pages for those, that show only the posts that belong to a specific taxonomy or category term. Don't work _against_ the system you are using.

Comment: Actually, I just learned about the taxonomies, thanks a lot, That really helped me

Comment: But is there any solution to get posts with the same title, because i have a lot of posts now (more than 120k) and i cant add each post to a taxonomy, so i really need now to get the posts with the same title to make the episodes list, and thanks again

Comment: _"and i cant add each post to a taxonomy"_ - you mean, you don't want to do it _manually_? Well, if you can determine the term from the title, then you could write a script that performs this update _once_ ...

Comment: `'post_title='the_title()''` - of course that did not work, that is not even valid PHP syntax, due to your use of quotes there. And you can not make a function call "inside" a text literal either. `'post_title="'.the_title().'"'` should probably work.

Comment: `'post_title="'.the_title().'"'` _ This one doesn't work, and for the script that performs the update, how i can make one? and what is the programming language needed for that? is php able to do that? sorry for all these questions, and I really appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

You must get the post type 'EpisodesList' in your WP Query. WP_Query is a class used in WordPress theming that accepts a variety of parameters to request and fetch posts around those parameters. The example below allows you to set a list of parameters, fetch the posts matching those parameters, and display the title and excerpt of the post on the website.

Code goes in your custom template file where you want to render the posts.

```
/**
 * Setup query to show the ‘EpisodesList’ post type with ‘8’ posts.
 * Output the title with an excerpt.
 */
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'EpisodesList',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
        'orderby’ => 'title', 
        'order’ => 'ASC', 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        print the_title(); 
        the_excerpt(); 
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that doen't work :(